# Model display is strange when memory limited is given in Autodesk Forge-Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Some components are hidden when memory limited are added.
Select a node with memory limited attached to the Autodesk Forge-viewer.
some of the unselected nodes will be hidden.
This happens on both PC and iOS.

[Before select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bsDk.png)

[After select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brhq1.png)

This IFCmodel create by Rebro.
I’ve tried some other model, but All with the same result.
The memory Limited are configuration as follows.

loaderExtensions: {svf: "Autodesk.MemoryLimited",},
memory: {
limit: 2560,
},

We checked both 7.4 and 7.63 versions of the viewer and this occurred in both

Do you know how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Is this an SVF1 model or SVF2? And can you reproduce the same behavior after increasing the memory limit? Does the rest of the model load eventually or is it just gone forever?

Comment: This is the SVF2 model.
This condition remained the same even after increasing the memory limit.
The model will display correctly by selecting a location where no members exist.

Comment: @PetrBorz
Check the comments above.